# Removing account from iCal to which I have lost access

Tags: ical

I have been syncing my iCal with a company email to which I have lost access.  I want to remove the company calendars from my iCal, but when I try opening iCal it continues to pop up the following exception:

```
Access to account “[Company Account]” is not permitted.

The server responded:
“403”
to operation CalDAVAccountRefreshQueueableOperation.
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Curious why the question was down voted... if anything I would imagine my answer was inadequate, though that's how I resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Kvass's solution, it wasn't easy to click the "accounts" in the split second after closing the error window, but I did it.

I then disabled each of my ical accounts and the error window went away.

Then I went back through activating each account one by one until the error message appeared again, narrowing down which account was the culprit.

I then disabled that account permanently and re-added the calendar events from that account to my good one. So far it's been 20 mins and it's working.

Not the most time efficient or technical solution, but I finally have relief!

Answer (score 0):

There may have been a better way to do this, but I was able to do it by quickly clicking "Accounts" in the Calendar menu in between the moments when the error would pop up.